# Kotlin Flow in Java

Tags: java, kotlin-coroutines

I have been trying to find some good resources that point to Kotlin Flow usage/integration in java applications but I couldn't find any.
Can we use Kotlin Flow (SharedFlow/StateFlow) in Kotlin based applications that might be integrated in other Java based projects.

Comment: You can't use flows directly from Java, but you can call Kotlin methods that use flows just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you can use any Kotlin APIs from Java, including flows and coroutines.

In *practice*, any attempt to use Flows *directly* from Java is likely to be so difficult to do correctly that you shouldn't bother trying.  So don't.  Instead, write Kotlin APIs that expose a non-coroutine API and *wrap* flows, and then use those from Java if you must.